# React useState not updating when called from Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I'm trying to create a resuable component that will be able to take a function passed down into it, allowing it to update the state of the parent component. I've got a demo on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-passing-function-to-child-component-hgx4f5?file=/src/App.tsx) that shows the issue.

TrackListing is passed the removeTrack function from the parent, and when the delete button is clicked inside the TrackListing, the function is called with the rows index to be removed from the tracks state. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to update the tracks state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your not changing the state, `tracks` it's the same `tracks`.

In JS if you do -> `var a = [1,23]; var b = a; console.log(a === b);` it would return `true`.  Assigning an array to another var, does not make a new array..  Doing `var a = [1,23]; var b = [...a]; console.log(a === b);` will do a shallow copy of a, and this as expected will return `false`. IOW: In react causing a state change.

Also `splice(index,index)`, I'm pretty sure you meant `splice(index, 1)`.

```
const removeTrack = (index: number) => {
    const t = tracks;
    t.splice(index, index);
    console.log(t);
    setTracks(t);  //t is still the same instance of t.
};
```

So you will need to make a copy of `t`.

```
const removeTrack = (index: number) => {
    const t = tracks;
    t.splice(index, 1);
    setTracks([...t]); //lets make a copy of `t` state has changed.
};
```

As pointed out in the comments, using the callback version of `setState` is a good idea, it will prevent issues of scope, here scope isn't an issue, but it's easy to get caught out by it.

Also another issue I've found with your current implementation you might want to look into, using array `index` as a key is not a good idea, it's not unique and you could get some funky rendering quirks, you really need unique `id`s for your tracks to use as the `key`

eg. This bit ->

```
tracks.map((track, index) => (
    <tr key={index}>   //not a good idea.

tracks.map((track, index) => (
    <tr key={track.id}>   //much better
```

Also when it comes to deleting, use the track id, using the callback/filter version in comments from Ali, you could also then just change `removeTrack(track:Track) {}`, and pass the track.  IOW: remove index array positions from all code.

I've done a fork of your CodeSandBox with these changes to make it easier.  [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-passing-function-to-child-component-forked-fgbcjr)

Comment: When the new state depends on the previous state, you pass a function to the state updating function, instead of a value. This guarantees that the value of the state variable is the most recent one

Comment: `const removeTrack = (index: number) => {
    setTracks(currentTracks => currentTracks.filter((track, i) => i !== index)
};`

Comment: Thank you, I did mean to put `.splice(index, 1)` and after reading your answer I feel very stupid as I've definitely used the spread operator when updating state in other JS projects before.

Comment: @AliNauman That doesn't work as the return from a splice is the elements you've spliced, not the array after the splice.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Updated to use filter

Comment: @AliNauman  Good point, although here it's not an issue because there is no scope problem, that's what the callback version really helps with, but certainly a good idea to get into the habit of doing.

Comment: @Keith, I'm in a situation where the tracks are being created with no actual id, but also going to be pulled from the db to edit later on. I'll see if I can switch to uuid's to fix that issue.

Comment: @ChazUK  Yes, UUID's are perfect for this sort of thing, if there is no obvious ID you can use..  In theory the key can even be the `name` if it's unique..